# How to plot a scatterplot with different point colors

Tags: r

I need to simulate 400 observations pairs of observations and plot a scatter plot of X1, X2 of the pairs of observations with a different set of colors in R. I used the following code below but I do not believe it is correct.

```
group <- rbinom(200, 1, 0.3) + 0                  # Create grouping variable

group_pch <- group                                # Create variable for symbols
group_pch[group_pch == 1] <- 16
group_pch[group_pch == 0] <- 16

group_col <- group                                # Create variable for colors
group_col[group_col == 1] <- "red"
group_col[group_col == 0] <- "green"

plot(x, y,                                        # Scatterplot with two groups
     pch = group_pch,
     col = group_col)
```

Comment: Just a note: You did not specify `x` and `y` in `plot()`, meaning you do not assign any vairables to the x- and y-axis of your scatterplot.

Comment: Does my answer help you?

Comment: I edited my post. The points are now red and green. Let me know if my answer helped you (For this, you have the option to accept my answer (green check)).

Answer (score 0):

First create a dataframe with 400 x- and y-values, here (X1, X2). I created the values by using random numbers generated with `rnorm()`, see `help(rnorm)` for details. Then I created a third variable, which returns the label `higher` if a respective x (X1) value is greater than 3 (mean) and `lower` if not. Again, see `help(cut)` for further information.

Finally, with `plot(x = df$X1, y = df$X2)` a simple scatterplot can be visualised. Using the argument `col = df$Color`, the points are seperated by color according to the `breaks = c(-Inf, 3, +Inf)`.

Unfortunately, from your question it is not clear how many colors/seperations/groups/... are required, and which rule should be used to differentiate between them.

```
# if you need to submit your code: 
set.seed(1209) # to make results reproducible; see: 
# ?set.seed()

# Create dataframe with 400 x and y-values 
df <- data.frame(
  X1 = rnorm(400, mean=3, sd=1),
  X2 = rnorm(400, mean=5, sd=3))

# Create new variable (color) for plotting
df$Color <- cut(df$X1, breaks = c(-Inf, 3, +Inf), 
                labels = c("lower", "higher"), 
                right = FALSE)
# Plot #1
# Plot the points and differentiate X1 smaller/greater 3 by color
plot(x = df$X1, y = df$X2, 
     col = df$Color, 
     main = "Plot Title", 
     pch = 19, cex = 0.5)
```

If you are asked to use specific colors, then do the following:

```
  # class(df$Color) # returns factor - perfect!
  preferredColors <- c("red", "green")[df$Color]
  # you need as many colors as labels, here 2 (lower, higher)

  # Plot #2
  plot(x = df$X1, y = df$X2, 
       col = preferredColors, 
       main = "Plot Title", 
       xlab = "Description of x-axes",
       ylab = "Description of y-axes",
       pch = 19, cex = 0.5)
```

Just for illustration; copy previous code only:

```
# output first three rows of the df for inspection purpose: 
head(df, n=3)
#>         X1         X2  Color
#> 1 2.450875  5.6721845  lower
#> 2 5.582115  4.8569917 higher
#> 3 2.324129 -0.3660018  lower
```

Created on 2021-09-12 by the reprex package (v2.0.1)

Output, Plot #2:

[image]